# I am getting linking error when compiling ICU 67.1 on Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC

Tags: c++, solaris, icu, xerces, solaris-studio

I am trying to compile ICU 67.1 on solaris 11 and facing error when it tries to make the tools/makeconv folder

Below is the error which I am getting:

```
/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -g -O4 -xlibmil  -mt  -std=c++11  -o 
../../bin/makeconv gencnvex.o genmbcs.o makeconv.o ucnvstat.o
-L../../lib -licutu -L../../lib -licui18n -L../../lib -licuuc -L../../stubdata -licudata -lpthread -lm  -mt

Undefined    first referenced symbol             in file
             uniset_getUnicode32Instance_67      ../../lib/libicuuc.so
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors
```

commands used

```
./runConfigureICU --enable-debug Solaris  --with-library-bits=32  --prefix=/scratch/mzishan/icu
gmake clean
gmake
```